# fire onPause on device back button but not on button click

Tags: android, onpause

I am opening new activity on button click of one activity. New Activity contains image button named go back. Now I want that when anyone click on back button of mobile device, it fires onPause or say close the application but when anyone clicks on go back image button, application does not fire onPause and it goes on last activity.
How to do it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have called finish() in your first activity while coming to this second activity and if you want to go to first activity again on click event of "go back" button in second activity, then you need to call an Intent to go from second activity to first activity.
But if you do not call finish() in your first activity while coming to this second activity and you want to go to first activity again on click event of "go back" button in second activity then simply call finish() on click event of "go back" button in second activity.

Comment: to pass values between activities you can use the code in my second answer.

Answer (score 0):

I saw your code from your other question, so you need to remove the `finish()` from onPause and add `finish()` to your "go back" button listener.

Do not call finish() if you want to keep it on the stack (in order to go back).

Example:

1. Activity A starts Activity B, which starts Activity C. (no finish() called yet)
2. Then when you go back from C, call finish() and you will
   see Activity B.
3. Then when you go back from B, call finish() and you will see Activity A.

Comment: finish() on "go back" close the app.

Comment: It only closes the app if this is the only activity on the stack. If you came to this screen from another activity, this is happening because you called finish() on the previous activity.

Comment: Well, this is the solution to your problem, maybe you should study a little bit more about android activity lifecycle (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html and http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can pass values between different activities.

```
 Intent i = new Intent(A.this, B.class); 
 i.putExtra("numbers", array); 
 startActivity(i);
```

Comment: no, i dont want to start new activity here. I am thinking to pass Boolean value and then check onPause() on last activity and then called finish() based on it.

Comment: That was just an example.You can also send Boolean values via intent. While going from activity A to activity B you can send your Boolean value. You can have this value received in activity B. Now in onPause() of activity B you can check this value and act accordingly.